# Can I import a png/jpg image like a component? React.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am doing a personal project in react.js but I would like to write clean code. Is there a way to import a png image into a component or something like that? I tried to convert it into a svg image but most of the converter pages do not work. If It can not be converted. You can answer with a nice converter page. thanks

for example

```
import { ReactComponent as AppIcon } from '../assets/img/icon_app.svg
```

and import it like this

```
<AppIcon />
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand this question.  What do you mean "convert a png to a component?"  What exactly is the result you are looking for?  An example of your _desired outcome_ would help inform the community in assisting you.

Comment: @AlexanderNied for example `import { ReactComponent as AppIcon } from '../assets/img/icon_app.svg` will result in `<AppIcon />`. but It doesnt work with png images just with svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
import yourImage from "./<path_to_png>/image.png"
```

Then use it like this:

```
<img src={yourImage} />
```

Comment: nice thanks! but there is not a way to put `yourImage` like `<yourImage />`

Comment: Not that I know of. What is the reason you would want to do that as opposed to putting it in an img tag?

Comment: It would be a more clean code I think. But your answer is nice! thanks!

Comment: Okay thats what I thought! I think this is the best practice for .png .jpg etc. Without the img tag it would be hard to set properties for the image. Remember you can always create your own image component! Thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Create React App, you already have a loader [link here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)
or else you can use a loader to bundle the img [url-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader)

then you will be able to do this
`import MyImage from 'path/to/img.png'`
and in the tag
`<img src={MyImage} />`

Or you can serve the png and add the link to the img tag like
`<img src="http://your-host.com/your-img.png" />`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!